# Fast python tutorial for Django beginners?

Tags: python, django

Is there a FAST python tutorial for Django beginners?

Comment: +1: Very Funny Question.  The "Royal Road" to Python.  If there was only a way to learn without taking time to learn.

Comment: Well, it depends on one's previous experience in programming ;-). I have some experience so a VERY FAST tutorial on python paradigms would be just what I need. Indeed, I need that Royal Road :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to learn Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726912/fastest-way-to-learn-python)

Comment: The point is that there is no royal road.  You **must** do some work.  Any tutorial can be done fast or slow.  If you are truly skilled, you can rip through **any** tutorial quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Python Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/). It's a 2-day class providing written matrial, lecture videos and exercises.

Comment: The link in the answer seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

This is small tutorial and fasted paced

- http://www.ibiblio.org/swaroopch/byteofpython/read/

I would suggest that you pick and choose the articles by Mertz from the "Charming python" columns

- http://gnosis.cx/publish/tech_index_cp.html

Python in 10 minutes :)

- http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python